# List all new commits based on the tip of my branch (from all branches including fetched remote ones) that are newer than my staging branch?

Tags: git

I'm looking for exact command to list all the commits from all existing branches that are not merged into my branch (including from remote branches that was fetched) that are based on the tip of my staging branch.

`git log --all --remotes` I use this to list all of the branches.

How do I exclude the once that I already have in the staging branch?

Comment: Define "newer than" in this context, are you talking strictly about timestamps? Do you mean "based on the tip of my branch"? Do you mean "not merged into my branch"?

Comment: Yep, thanks for clarifying terms, let me edit these terms clearly.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I did update it, but you understood correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `git log --branches --remotes ^staging`, or equivalently, `git log ^staging --branches --remotes`.

You can use `--all` if you mean *all references* (including tags, notes, `refs/stash`, etc), but you specifically said branches and remote-tracking names, for which `--branches` and `--remotes` produce the correct match.  Note that `--branches` and `--remotes` may be followed by `=<pattern>` to match specific name patterns.

The trick here is that the negation syntax (`^X`, or `--not` followed by `X`) tells the revision-walk code to exclude the commit named `X` and any commit reachable from `X`.  Positive references give `git log` places to *start;* negative references give `git log` places to *stop;* and `git log` then loops over a priority queue that contains commits that are yet to be visited.  So, initially, the queue looks at (contains hash IDs of) all branch tips and all remote-tracking-name tips, in some order.  Git visits the first such commit, unless it's excluded, i.e., is at the tip of `staging` or reachable from the tip of `staging`.  Git puts that commit's parent into the queue, then visits the next commit in the queue (unless it's excluded, as before).

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to excluded cherrypicked commits as well?

Comment: @Pol: there isn't, not for *this* case anyway. To find cherry-picked equivalent commits, use `git patch-id`. When using the three-dot symmetric difference notation, as in `git rev-list A...B`, `git rev-list` can be instructed to compute the patch ID of each commit on both "sides" of the difference operation, and then mark up its output. See [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html) and look for `--left-right --cherry-mark`, then read the other `cherry` options as well. Note that you can write your *own* scripts using `git rev-list` output, [cont'd]

Comment: as `git rev-list` is designed to produce machine-readable (not very human-readable) output. You can therefore use `git rev-list` to enumerate the commits reachable from staging but not others, and vice versa, and then do your own `git show $hash | git patch-id` to compute patch IDs and construct whatever is useful to you.

Comment: Thanks @torek. Very informative comment. I seems like I'm not getting some of the concepts. I see it as bit overcomplicated, need to do some reading. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: It definitely is complicated. "Over-complicated" is kind of a matter of opinion :-) as each of the things that complicates this exists for valid reasons. For a discussion of graph theory, why it matters, and what "reachablity" means, see http://think-like-a-git.net/